# Calculate the direction, From Outer Polygon Point to Inner Polygon inside Point

Tags: xna, c++, mathematics, algorithm, vector

I was able to find the co-ordinates of inner Polygon using this trick.

[Need the co-ordinates of innerPolygon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27250/need-the-co-ordinates-of-innerpolygon)

But, I have some problem in getting the direction from Outer Polygon Point to Inner Polygon inside Point? See this image, I need to make sure that the direction should be from inner to outer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to have a parsing convention for your polygon. Once you adopt this for all your polygons, the answer is immediate. For instance, the following picture illustrates “when parsing the list of points, the inside of the polygon is always on the right”:

[image: polygon parsing]

Now what if you don't have this information yet? Here is one simple technique:

- find the leftmost point of the polygon, call it `A = P[n]`; if there are several such points, pick the uppermost
- pick the previous point and the next point in the list, `B = P[n-1]` and `C = P[n+1]`
- compute the z coordinate of cross product `AB × AC`, *aka.* `z = (B.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y) - (C.x - A.x) * (B.y - A.y)`
- if `z` is positive, the inside of the polygon is **on the right when parsing the list of points**.
- if `z` is negative, the inside of the polygon is **on the left when parsing the list of points**.

Note that the above needs only to be done once per polygon.

Now when you travel from `A` to `B`, a simple vector pointing to the **left** of the path is `(A.y - B.y, B.x - A.x)`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be little complex. I was thinking that it is very easy.

Comment: @user960567 I believe it *is* very easy; maybe I wasn't clear enough? I'll update the answer a bit.

Comment: I don't get 'on the right when parsing the list of points'.

Comment: @user960567 when you parse the list of points making the polygon, you follow a path; on one side of the path there is the inside of the polygon and on the other side there is the outside. The test decides whether the inside is on the left side or on the right side of the path.

Comment: But in programming, there is no left or right. I need to use + or - during moving distance d from a point p with vector v.

Comment: @user960567 I added a note about what I mean by left and right; is it clearer?

Comment: Formula, newPoint = oldPoint + distance * vector / magnitude or newPoint = oldPoint - distance * vector / magnitude

Comment: OK, I think I got your point now. Thanks, appreciated.